# Ionic Form Can't Change Option on Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a form in Ionic, including a dropdown list. Previously, I had the following code:

```
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <span class="input-label">* Age</span>
                <select ng-model="data.child1.age" required>
                    <option ng-value="7">Year 7 (11-12)</option>
                    <option ng-value="8">Year 8 (12-13)</option>
                    <option ng-value="9">Year 9 (13-14)</option>
                    <option ng-value="10">Year 10 (14-15)</option>
                    <option ng-value="11">Year 11 (15-16)</option>
                    <option ng-value="12">Year 12 (16-17)</option>
                    <option ng-value="13">Year 13 (17-18)</option>
                </select>
            </label>
```

The problem with this is that when I loaded in previously saved data (from a DB), the view would not update to match the model.

So, after some research, I tried this instead:

```
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <span class="input-label">* Age</span>
                <select ng-model="data.child1.age" ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in ageOptions" required></select>
            </label>
```

Where ageOptions looks like this:

```
             $scope.ageOptions = [
                {id: 7, label: "Year 7 (11-12)"},
                {id: 8, label: "Year 8 (12-13)"},
                {id: 9, label: "Year 9 (13-14)"},
                {id: 10, label: "Year 10 (14-15)"},
                {id: 11, label: "Year 11 (15-16)"},
                {id: 12, label: "Year 12 (16-17)"},
                {id: 13, label: "Year 13 (17-18)"}
             ]
```

However, although the view now updates fine and matches the model, I can't actually change the selected option! More specifically, clicking on the form element doesn't actually do anything (ie open the dropdown box).

I have looked around a bit but couldn't find anything on this.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I made a simple demo of your code. Is this what is the situation with what you mean by updating the options (which is made with timeout in my demo): https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/55h5uyh1/

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want. Right now mine looks the same but clicking on the box doesn't do anything, ie I can't select an option. I don't really understand why the timeout makes it work; it seems rather hacky?

Comment: Yeah well the timeout is there just to change the value so the demo has the same effect as you updating the values from getting them from your DB. I don't know why you would not be able to select the value after updating the values though.

Comment: To clarify, even if I don't load anything in from the DB the dropdown doesn't work. Looking at the HTML in the browser I see this: <option value="?" selected="selected"></option> I don't know if that helps or is normal behaviour.

Comment: Well that would indicate that something else is going wrong in your code somewhere. My JSFiddle works fine for you right? And there should be value in the option  with the given `ageOptions`.

Comment: It turns out that my code, and your fiddle, work in Firefox; the problem only occurs in Chrome. Fortunately, I just built and ran it on my phone and it does work there...

Comment: Ok, well I'm using Chrome 53 and it works for me so must be something specific to your browser. But glad you got it working.

Comment: I am having exact problem, it works with firefox but when I use chrome (ver 53) clicking on the selectbox  does not open the options